# How to invert a sine wave so that the output is 180 degrees out of phase with the input?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, sine, inverting-amplifier

I'm sure there is fairly simply op-amp circuit that will do this, however I lack the experience to design it myself.

Comment: An inverting amplifier? Text-book opamps 101.

Comment: The '741 is 48 years old. It is almost never the best choice for a real circuit these days. The best choice depends on the frequency and amplitude of your signal, what load is being driven, what power supplies you have available, ...

Comment: Unfortunately, where I live I only have access to a radioshack that carries the 741 and tl082 OpAmps. I am using the circuit to invert a signal generator signal in order to create the phenomenon of destructive interference.

Comment: Don't modify your question to ask a new question. Ask a separate, new question instead and accept the right answer to your original question here.

Comment: Fair enough, will do so in the future. I'm new here (:

Answer (score 1):

The inverting amplifier is one of the first op-amp circuits you should learn:

[image]

([image source](http://ecetutorials.com/analog-electronics/inverting-and-non-inverting-amplifiers/))

If Rf = Ri, the gain will be -1.

This circuit is probably good up to 100's of MHz, if you choose the right op-amp. You'll want to watch out for both the gain-bandwidth product and the slew rate specs to find the right op-amp.

Comment: Thank you so much! Im a junior in high school looking to go into electrical engineering, do you have any recommendations as to where I could get some pre-university knowledge? Is the art of electronics all I need?

Comment: Art of Electronics is a good start. You'll also want to have at least Algebra and Geometry as math background to be able to understand what's going on.

Comment: The foundational math is no issue, however I'm about 75% through AB Calculus (covering basic differentiation/integration). What should I pay attention to in particular for electronics purposes?

Comment: Then you're way ahead of the curve. Keep up the math. Abstract algebra, number theory, etc., all go into signal processing, which is one of the EE areas that's likely to remain employable in the US (assuming that's where  you are).

Comment: @The photon: Most important is not be scared by the math. For engineers, it's just a tool. You are always allowed to look things up. No chance when you don't know the basics, though.

Comment: @user96033: go play with vectors and complex numbers. Then learn about differential equations. Then about Fourier-, Laplace- and Z transformations. Program a lot. Create you own wimpy little computer algebra system. Create programs which solve/simulate simple circuits. You learn a lot doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a transformer. If you swap the two output wires it will invert your signal.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, are there any drawbacks when compared to the inverting OpAmp method?

Answer (score 1):

To invert a sine wave, you can make a simple circuit using just 2 resistors.

The resistor version of the inverter has limitations :  beware of where you are connecting ground.  Also, the circuit has a high output impedance.  If the load to be connected is capacitive, the angle (180 degrees) will be affected.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNKH3x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Also, the output voltages Vo1  and Vo2  will be half of the voltage of V1.

Vo1 and Vo2 are 180 degrees out of phase with each other.

Answer (score 0):

With an inverting amplifier. See picture for an example. [image: example]

Do you need any gain in the circuit or just invert it?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an "inverting" amplifier. 
It's a classical op-amp configuration:

[image]

There are online "Inverting op-amp gain calculator" applications that can simplify component selection for you.

There's too much to explain, so you need to do some training...try [this](https://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/mastascu/eLessonsHTML/OpAmps/OpAmp2.html) as a simple starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Several of the canned examples in this tool present INVERTING OP AMP circuits.

You will learn about tuned/resonant circuits, about opamps as low-pass-filters, about ClassB power amplifiers, if you download and install (Windows 7/8/10) the *free* tool Signal Wave Explorer at the website

robustcircuitdesign.com

Just click on "examples", "scope probe ringing", "run" {3 clicks}.
You can edit the input signal; find the "signal [trapezoid]" and edit that menu,
to have a sinusoidal input, or other wave shapes if you wish.
I think there is a UserManual; yes, its under HELP.

There are 14 canned examples, with editable parameters. For the LRC circuit (the scope probe that rings), you chose inductance, capacitance, resistance.

We particularly need feedback on how understandable the examples are, and how clear the menus are. Don't be shy.

And enjoy the learning. There is a 2nd tool, focused on OpAmps and interference: Signal Chain Explorer.